# multi action rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have an Controller X which which has an action new.

As part of the creation process, I would like to handle multiple things before the form is submitted.

Three operations I would like to do is Search, Evaluate and Create.

So when the view is first loaded, it will have the form to input some fields. Based on the input, I need to call some ruby utils to build the "data" object and then display those results back to the page. I think I have this part figured out, I have a form_for('/x/new') tag in my view and I check in my controller if request.post? then calculate data object.

But when the search is done and the data is rendered back to the page, user can evaluate it which is another operation call that can grab some additional data. When the user clicks on evaluate/search or create button, how do I figure out which button was clicked?

Comment: what is the essence of your question? i didn't get it. you can give buttons a name, so that you know which one got clicked. is that it?

Answer (score 0):

It's best practise (because its more RESTfull) if you split up your action in different action/views!